# Processing a list of atomic operations, allowing for interruptions

Tags: design-patterns

I'm looking for a design pattern that addresses the following situation:

1. There exists a list of tasks that must be processed.
2. Tasks may be added at any time.
3. Each task is wholly independent from all other tasks.
4. The order in which tasks are processed has no effect on the overall system or on the tasks themselves.
5. Every task must be processed once and only once.
6. The "main" process which launches the task processors may start and stop without warning. When stopped, the "main" process loses all in-memory data.

Obviously this is going to involve some state, but are there any design patterns which discuss where and how to maintain that state? Are there any relevant anti-patterns?

Named patterns are especially helpful so that we can discuss this topic with other organizations without having to describe the entire problem domain.

Comment: Sounds similar to this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern

Comment: Thanks @Doval, I've found many patterns dealing with lists. The key is the last part - the "main" process might be interrupted (ie shutdown), meaning it will lose it's state. The next time it's started, it'll basically need to pick back up where it left off.

Comment: You say the operations are atomic - what happens if the `main` shuts down mid task?

Comment: Looking for patterns before you've figured out how to solve the problem is an anti-pattern.

Comment: @Blrfl - I know how to solve the problem for our particular situation. It's pretty straight-forward - use a persistent data store such as a database to maintain the state of each task between invocations of the main process. This would be similar to the audit trail pattern. Now I'm looking for a pattern that describes solutions to this problem in more general terms.

Comment: @Bobson - That's a possibility, but that's a problem for any list processor. http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/My-Tales.aspx The solution would be to record the start of a task and the completion of a task. If the main process is interrupted, Tasks that were started and not completed would require some special processing (perhaps manual intervention) to determine what should be done. But this would be a very exceptional situation in my implementation.

Comment: If you *need* a pattern name to represent what you're doing, *Command* (GoF) should suffice. Otherwise *Unit of Work* (from Fowler's Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture). Neither is a perfect fit.

Comment: If you *aren't* simply looking for a name, but actually for a solution, I'd suggest a database or persistent queue.